# Cycling through array elements efficiently in python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm trying to sum the elements of separate data array by their characteristics efficiently.  I have three identifying characteristics (age, year, and cause) in a given array, and for each age, year, cause, I have 1000 values.  I need to add those values to another data array when the characteristics are the same.  For now, I'm doing something like this where each datasets is ~ (80000, 1000):

```
import numpy as np
datasets = np.vstack(dataset1, dataset2)
for a in ages:
    for y in years:
        for c in causes:
             output = np.sum(datasets[(age==a) & (year==y) & (cause==c)], axis = 0)
```

However, with 60,000 iterations, this is incredibly slow.   The challenge is that the arrays don't necessarily all have the same shape.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I thought of the groupby function of matplotlib.mlab. This would be something like this: `matplotlib.mlab.rec_groupby(datasets, groupby = ('age', 'year', 'cause', ), stats = (('values', np.sum, 'sums' ), ))` with a structured array with age, year and cause as fields and values as a field with an array of length 1000. But the problem is that I have not figured out how you can pass the `axis = 0` argument with this. Because now it sums all 1000 values of the different rows to one total sum.

Comment: I found a great result here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416901/summing-arrays-by-characteristics-in-python

Comment: Ten years after asking this question, things have changed: Nowadays there is this package doing the job for you: https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEE LINK BELOW

I'm not sure how to properly link another answer to this answer.  When I tried one sentence followed by the link, it converted the answer to a comment.  I'm now being long-winded to try and make stack-overflow think that this text is long enough to constitute an answer.  Here is the link to a great answer to this question.

[Summing Arrays by Characteristics in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416901/summing-arrays-by-characteristics-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend something like accumarray.  Your output should be a 3-dimensional data cube where each dimension corresponds to a variable (age, year, cause).  Each index in each dimension corresponds to a unique value in your input lists.  You can then use something like this [cookbook example](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/AccumarrayLike) to accumulate the datasets variable into the appropriate bins using age, year, and cause.

You might also consider using a proper relational database.  They're quite fast at these sorts of things.  Python ships with [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) as a part of the core.  Unfortunately, it's a rather steep learning curve if you've never worked with a relational database before.  You'll want to use the `group` and `aggregate` functionality.